# Gender labels on trainer badges in Pokémon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

The badges that appear in Pokémon Go – "Jogger", "Kanto", "Collector", &c. – have gendered labels for some of them, notably (on my account) "Battle Girl", "Punk Girl" and "Fairy Tale Girl".

Does everyone get "Girl", or does the game give some people "Boy" or similar instead? If different people get different things, does anyone know how the game decides?

I don't object at all, I'm just mildly surprised given I selected the more masculine-looking avatar and the only gender I've had associated with my Google account is male.

Comment: I believe it is a reference to npc from the games, and not a thing determined by your gender. ~lacking sources, hence as comment

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The names of the badges correspond with the type of trainers you can find in game of the main Pokemon games. They are not based of the type or character you have created.

Here is a list of all [Trainer Classes](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Trainer#List_of_Trainer_classes) that exist in all Pokemon Games.

Comment: If you're familiar with the trainer classes in the games, a large number of them are male exclusive as well, despite not having a gendered name. Hiker, ruin maniac, bug catcher, black belt, etc. A few of them have both, like psychic and skier.